# define top in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a "Frankenstein" code like this:

```
<body>
  <iframe src="ThirdPartyPage">
    <... id="foo">
    <iframe>
      ...
      top.document.getElementById(foo)
      ...
    </iframe>
  </iframe>
</body>
```

Is there a way to say to the javascript that the top is not my code, but the ThirdPartyPage instead?

EDIT: The problem here in not how to get "foo". The problem here is that the third party page is tring to get the "foo" from the top, but now with the new iframe, the top in no longer the third party page.

Comment: Say us what you need to do. It is not very clear what is ur code and third party code or what you mean by third party.

Answer (score 1):

```
//To get the parent node i.e. ThirdPartyPage

document.getElementById("yourFrameId").parentNode 

//Also you could get the elements within the ThirdPartyPage as follows (returns an array of elements)

document.getElementById("yourFrameId").parentNode.getElementsByTagName("tagName")
```

Comment: I've added an "edit" to the question to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't over write `top` and you can't also access any DOM Element using `getElementById(foo)` from an `iframe`

Comment: the getElementById(foo) worked before the new iframe around the third party page. But with the new iframe, now the top is different and is breaking the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent), not window.top.